# tinyMCE ajaxfilemanager import any file

Tags: javascript, file, import, tinymce

How to use TinyMCE with ajaxfilemanager import any file?
How do I add an icon to the toolbar import, try them on the

```
theme_advanced_buttons1:"insertfile"
```

But do not show this icon in the toolbar

Comment: have you purchased the filemanager? http://www.tinymce.com/enterprise/mcfilemanager.php

Comment: I change the site that was created by someone else. I can import images and video, but the not file (Have check whether the plug is purchased?)

Comment: somewhere you should have a directory `jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins`, check in there for a folder named `filemanager`

Comment: I do not have :( if there is any free plug-in to tnyMCE?